# Equivalent of RTLD_NEXT when importing modules in Python?

Tags: python, module, python-3.x, hook

I'm attempting to "hook" a top level standard library module. That is, provide an alternative implementation, however I need to invoke some of the functionality from the original module.

How can I import the "next module in line", similar to the effect that `RTLD_NEXT` has on [`dlopen`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/dlopen) in Linux?

Comment: Maybe something like this? [How to mock an import](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8658332/1052325)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much mucking about, I found the best strategy is just to monkey patch the modules directly. There's no way to police all the references involved if the real module is shadowed. Here's [an example](https://bitbucket.org/anacrolix/goco/src/fdf0f75a21c0/goco.py).