# How to mock python module in unittest

Tags: python, mocking

I have a problem when mocking in unittest.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys
sys.modules["foo.Bar"] = __import__("mock_bar")
import foo.Bar
print foo.Bar.__name__
```

I've got an `ImportError` exception in line 4. I don't know why since I have do some mock at line 3. There is a reference of how to mock import [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8658043/how-to-mock-an-import).
Here's the error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 4, in <module>
    import foo.Bar
ImportError: No module named foo.Bar
```

"import foo.Bar" should equal to "__import__('foo.Bar')", and before that I've hacked sys.modules to pretend module 'foo.Bar' has been already imported. Why python still try to import foo.Bar and complain?

Comment: @MartijnPieters Sorry for my clerical error

Comment: Is there a `foo` module?

Comment: @MartijnPieters Actually, "foo" is a package name and "Bar" is a module name. The "foo/Bar.py" is the target which I want to mock. So there's no "foo/Bar.py" file, but "mock_bar.py" instead.

Comment: Yeah, understood that. Any reason you are using `__import__` instead of the `importlib` module, btw.?

Comment: Because I'm using python2.5, no Python3

Comment: `importlib` was added in Python 2.7 too, but that won't help you either.

Comment: What is the point of mocking an non-existing module ? That's actually not mocking. If you wan't to just have o mock at foo.Bar, then make up some objects too assing `foo.Bar = mock.Mock()`

Answer (score 0):

Try doing `import foo` before your `__import__` line: I think it could help.