# How do I mock and unit test the following code?

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking

```
import module
from x import X

class A:
   def method(): 
       return module.something(arg=X())
```

I created the following to unit test:

```
with patch('filename.module.something') as something_mock:
   with patch('filename.X'): as x_mock:
       a.method()
something_mock.assert_called_once_with(arg=x_mock.return_value)
x_mock.assert_called_once_with()
```

Someone mentioned that there is no need to mock `filenme.X` without an explanation. Is there other way to verify the call to `something` without mocking `filename.X`? How would I change the following assertion to verify the call?

```
something_mock.assert_called_once_with(arg=_____)
```

Comment: If your code really looks like the example given, what's the point of unit testing it all all? There's nothing happening at this level of the code -- no logical, algorithmic, or data complexity at all. FWIW, with each passing year I find myself mocking less and less, writing fewer unit tests, and writing more (and more interesting) integration or end-to-end tests that exercise larger components of the system.

Comment: @FMc The code is simplified for clarity

Comment: This answer might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8658043/how-to-mock-an-import

Comment: @FMc ... interesting... I did exactly the reverse path :). IMHO integration tests are less useful without good and extensive unit tests: when an integration test fail unit test give to you a very solid base on what you can trust and where you can have some holes in your code/design.

Answer (score -1):

If create `X` is not a issue (i.e. db connection or network access) you can do your test without mock it.

You have follow alternatives:

1. Use `mock`'s `called` attribute if you are not interested to check how your method call `something_mock`
2. Use [`mock.ANY`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#any) if you would like to check that `something_mock` has called by `arg` keyword arg but you are not interested about what is the value
3. Use [`call_args`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.Mock.call_args) to extract `something_mock` call arguments and by [*calls as tuple*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#calls-as-tuples) extract `arg` value

The first one is

```
assert something_mock.called
```

The second one is

```
something_mock.assert_called_once_with(arg=mock.ANY)
```

Finally the third one is

```
args, kwargs = something_mock.call_args
assert isinstance(kwarg['arg'], x.X)
```

Last option is quite the same to mock `X` but I wrote it just to show all possibilities.