# Mock an import from an import

Tags: python, testing, mocking

I followed the instructions on [How to mock an import](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8658043/how-to-mock-an-import)

but I'm having no success.

I have the following setup:

`Class A` imports `Class B`, and `Class B` imports `Class C`.

`Class C` is the module I want to mock.

in `test.py`:

```
import sys
from mock import Mock
sys.modules['C'] = Mock()
import A
print A.C.__name__ // this returns: 

AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'C'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be `A.B.C.__name__` like this:

```
import sys
from mock import Mock
sys.modules['C'] = Mock()
import A
print A.B.C.__name__
```