# mock import in Python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, unit-testing

I have an import in the format:

```
from a.b.c.d import x
```

in foo.py. I am testing bla.py, which does not import foo.py directly, but indirectly in one of its methods. Something like:

bla.m1() --> bla2.m2() --> foo.m3()

In my test environment, package "a" is not available and I'd like to mock it so that the import does not fail during the test. According to [How to mock an import](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8658043/how-to-mock-an-import), I could do it using:

```
import sys
from unittest.mock import Mock
sys.modules['a.b.c.d'] = Mock()
```

The import works in the test code if I'm using Python 3, but it fails when I use Python 2.7 (and the external mock library). Why? How can I make it work in Python 2.7?

Comment: Seems like the right fix is to *put* package `a` in your test environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Python 2.7 you need to explicitly create each level of the mocked module as something 'truthy' - as python check that the object exists (even if it doesn't actually do anything with it.

The easiest option is to also make them `Mock` methods, in case you ever want to test them:

```
import sys
from mock import Mock

sys.modules['a'] = Mock()
sys.modules['a.b'] = Mock()
sys.modules['a.b.c'] = Mock()

from a.b.c import d
print(d)
```

> `<Mock name='mock.d' id='140035843407120'>`

However the following is also perfectly valid:

```
import sys
from mock import Mock

sys.modules['a'] = 'cat'
sys.modules['a.b'] = 1
sys.modules['a.b.c'] = Mock()

from a.b.c import d
print(d)
```

> `<Mock name='mock.d' id='1402443407120'>`