# flake8 linting for databricks python code in github using workflows

Tags: python, apache-spark, github, databricks, flake8

I have my databricks python code in `github`. I setup a basic workflow to lint the python code using `flake8`. This fails because the names that are implicitly available to my script (like `spark`, `sc`, `dbutils`, `getArgument` etc) when it runs on databricks are not available when `flake8` lints it outside databricks (in github ubuntu vm).

How can I lint databricks notebooks in `github` using `flake8`?

E.g. **errors I get:**

```
test.py:1:1: F821 undefined name 'dbutils'
test.py:3:11: F821 undefined name 'getArgument'
test.py:5:1: F821 undefined name 'dbutils'
test.py:7:11: F821 undefined name 'spark'
```

**my notebook in github:**

```
dbutils.widgets.text("my_jdbcurl", "default my_jdbcurl")

jdbcurl = getArgument("my_jdbcurl")

dbutils.fs.ls(".")

df_node = spark.read.format("jdbc")\
  .option("driver", "org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver")\
  .option("url", jdbcurl)\
  .option("dbtable", "my_table")\
  .option("user", "my_username")\
  .option("password", "my_pswd")\
  .load()
```

**my .github/workflows/lint.yml**

```
on:
  pull_request:
    branches: [ master ]

jobs:
  build:

    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v2
    - uses: actions/setup-python@v1
      with:
        python-version: 3.8
    - run: |
        python -m pip install --upgrade pip
        pip install -r requirements.txt
    - name: Lint with flake8
      run: |
        pip install flake8
        flake8 . --count --select=E9,F63,F7,F82 --show-source --statistics
```

Comment: You should find out how databricks invokes `flake8`, including what dependencies it provides.  That will tell you how you should invoke `flake8` in GitHub Actions..

Comment: @bk2204, I didn't quite get that. In this case it's github invoking `flake8` not databricks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TL;DR

Don't use the built-in variable `dbutils` in code that would need to run locally (IDE, Unit tests, ...) and in Databricks (production). Create your own instance of `DBUtils` class instead.

---

Here is what we ended up doing:

Created a new `dbk_utils.py`

```py
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

def get_dbutils(spark: SparkSession):
    try:
        from pyspark.dbutils import DBUtils
        return DBUtils(spark)

    except ModuleNotFoundError:
        import IPython
        return IPython.get_ipython().user_ns["dbutils"]
```

And update the code that uses `dbutils` to use this utility:

```
from dbk_utils import get_dbutils

my_dbutils = get_dbutils()

my_dbutils.widgets.text("my_jdbcurl", "default my_jdbcurl")
my_dbutils.fs.ls(".")

jdbcurl = my_dbutils.widgets.getArgument("my_jdbcurl")

df_node = spark.read.format("jdbc")\
  .option("driver", "org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver")\
  .option("url", jdbcurl)\
  .option("dbtable", "my_table")\
  .option("user", "my_username")\
  .option("password", "my_pswd")\
  .load()
```

If you're trying to do unit testing as well, then check out:

- [How to mock an import](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76018686/496289) and
- [ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyspark.dbutils'](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76019496/496289)

Answer (score 2):

One thing you can do is this:

```py
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession


spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()
```

This will work with or without Databricks, in normal Python or in the `pyspark` client.

To detect if you are in a file or in a Databricks notebook, you can run:

```py
try:
    __file__
    print("We are in a file, like in our IDE or being tested by flake8.")
except NameError:
    print("We are in a Databricks notebook. Act accordingly.")
```

You could then conditionally initialize or create dummy variables for `display()` and other tools.

This is only a partial solution. I am working on a better solution, I will keep this answer updated.

Comment: how do we handle dbutils?

Comment: @JamesOwers

```python
from pyspark.dbutils import DBUtils


dbutils = DBUtils()
```

This works in normal `pyspark`, on Databricks vis `databricks-connect` or on Databricks notebooks.

Answer (score 1):

This is my opinion, all linters dont work for all use cases, this is what I do. I am using a pre-commit hook and ignoring rule `F821`.

```
# Flake rules: https://lintlyci.github.io/Flake8Rules/
- repo: https://gitlab.com/pycqa/flake8
  rev: 3.8.4
  hooks:
    - id: flake8
      exclude: (^docs/)
      additional_dependencies: [flake8-typing-imports==1.7.0]
      # F821 undefined name
      args:
        [
          "--max-line-length=127",
          "--config=setup.cfg",
          "--ignore=F821",
        ]
```

To match your syntax, add the `--ignore` flag:

```
flake8 . --count --exit-zero --max-complexity=10 --max-line-length=127 --ignore=C901,F821 --statistics
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add --builtins=dbutils,spark,display to ignore variables that are built into Databricks IDE

Comment: but you will hit the next issue, which is functions imported with `%run` being recognized as undefined. curious if anyone has a solution to that. so far, I've tried flake8_nb and nbqa, both seem to require that the notebook being imported has an .ipynb file extension, but Databricks syntax leaves out that extension.

Comment: Added a solution/answer. Also `--builtins=dbutils,spark,display` would satisfy `flake8` but in the long term, in production code, you'll need to run unit tests and so on, so you'll end up creating local spark sessions, so...