# Mock environment variables inside __init__ file

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-unittest.mock

have a question about mocking environment variables
The module has this structure

```
sharepoint
|-- __init__.py (Here I initialize some variables I used in get_file and get_token)
|-- get_file.py
|-- get_token
__init__.py
main.py
```

So, I'm trying to test some get_file methods, the first line you see in get_file.py is this one:

```
from . import SHAREPOINT_URL, FOLDER_PATH, LIMIT_HOURS, CONTENT_TYPE
```

As you can see, I get them from environment in __init__.py

```
FULL_CLIENT, SECRET, SHAREPOINT_URL, FOLDER_PATH, LIMIT_HOURS = [environ[k] for k in ['FULL_CLIENT', 'SECRET', 'SHAREPOINT_URL', 'FOLDER_PATH', 'LIMIT_HOURS']]
```

When I'm trying to unit test a method, an error appears because I didn't set the environment variables before.

`ERROR tests/test_sharepoint.py - KeyError: 'FULL_CLIENT'`

I've already tried to mock with

```
@mock.patch.dict(os.environ, {"FULL_CLIENT": 'full_client', 'SECRET': 'secret', 'SHAREPOINT_URL': 'url', 'FOLDER_PATH': 'path', 'LIMIT_HOURS': 'hours'})
```

but it seems that it's unreachable for unit test to mock it before enters to the get_file.py.

Can you help me with that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you should read this:
[How to mock an import](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8658043/how-to-mock-an-import)

However, the good practice is to wrap the retrieval of the environment variables inside dedicated function and mock this function instead. This is clean and universal solution.

Comment: You're right, I'm gonna wrap the environment variables in a method. Thanks!